# Array shuffle function not touching last element

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am using this function to shuffle a 4 element array. It shuffles the first 3 elements well, shuffling them randomly, but the last element is only sometimes shuffled around with the other three.

```
public function shuffleArray(objA:Object, objB:Object):int{
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 2) - 1;
}
```

Comment: your ordering isn't providing a consistent order; it could say that A > B, B > C and C > A. So the result won't be well defined (depends on the choice of sorting algorithm). There are better shuffling methods you could use.

Comment: What are you expecting the outcome to be? Random is random, it's possible that with your algorithm, it could return 0 every time `shuffleArray` is called as the sort method, thus causing all elements to be left in their original order.

Comment: As a matter of fact the method cannot return 0 every time (the more you run it the less it's possible to get the same resul). As for all probability study when tested on large scale (100k+) the results should start to even out.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really wrong with it. That's random. As mentioned, the algorithm used for `Math.random()` makes the difference and I don't believe the AS3 algorithm is especially good.

For testing purposes, I ran it a few times in JS and saw very similar things, where a specific index was the same quite a few times in a row. My results were showing 5-10 times in a row, the one of the indexes would be exactly the same. In a few tests, I saw the *exact* same result appear 11 times in a row. Running it with a higher `maxValue` (I tried 15) resulted in a much more random outcome, though it still had the same problems. Interestingly, bumping the iterations up seemed to break the pattern. I noticed it became slightly more random as we got higher in tries (I tried 10k).

```
var maxValue = 4,
    iterations = 100,
    a = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= maxValue; i++) {
    a.push(i);
}

function shuffle(a, b) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 2) - 1;
}

for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    console.log(a.sort(shuffle));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KA2tf/1/

I did test the same code in Flash (with some minor alterations for AS3, obviously) and saw mostly similar results (to be expected; I believe Flash and JS use very similar algorithms, if not the same one). There's only 24 different combinations a 4 item array can be sorted. You're bound to get repetition.

Comment: You may have discover how probability works, congrats. On a more serious note random either in JS or Flash is not flawed as you claim. Incidentally the problem reported here could be the method or the study of its effects. Since the method works correctly there can be only one solution, the user is mistaken about that method producing a wrong result. Notice how he never precise how many times he has witnessed the wrong result. As probability taught us, the method should be tested a large number of time (100k+) so that the results can even out and prove the solution.

Comment: @BotMaster Other than saying the random function is not very good (I read an article a few years ago saying it was a weak algorithm, built for speed rather than real randomness, though I have no links handy), my answer pretty much matches your comment. I tested 10k and it started to even out. I said there was only 24 combinations and it was bound to repeat for that reason. Even said it's to be expected and there's nothing wrong with it. Your comment seems to attempt to be sarcastically contrary but it actually just re-states what my answer said...